# Python Regex: finding all the possible hits for specific keywords

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python and trying to find a best way to search for some specific keywords 'coming soon', 'under construction', 'page not found' and 'forbidden'. I need to find all possible hits for those strings example: 'coming soon', 'Coming Soon', 'coMInG SoOn' etc.

I've tried:

```
re.compile("^coming soon$", re.I))
```

and

```
re.compile("coming soon", re.I))
```

or

```
re.compile("\W*((?i)coming soon(?-i))\W*", re.I))
```

but with no luck so far. Would someone be able to help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `re.compile("coming soon", re.I)` works, doesn't it?

Comment: The second one should work, assuming you use `search` and not `match`(see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)). If you did that, please also post the code showing how you are using the created regex object.

Comment: I've been using it together with this bit of code: `"coming soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("coming soon", re.I))` and this would throw some false positives for some of the URLs I've been scanning for this keyword. Do you think this bit is correct and my issue would be linked to something else? Thanks!

Comment: Please show a *complete* example - enough code so that you can say "here is my input; here is the *exact* output I expect for this input; here is the *exact* output I actually get".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option. You can use **re.findall** and also modify your regex pattern itself to find all matches using case-insensitive match `(?i)`:

```py
words = re.findall("(?i)coming soon", text)
print(words)
```

It'll output:

```
['coming soon', 'coming soon', 'Coming Soon', 'coMInG SoOn']
```

Also, you can search for all 4 phrases at the same time:

```py
words = re.findall("(?i)coming soon|under construction|page not found|forbidden", text)
print(words)
```

As a general recommendation, when using regex you can always test your statement using [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/). Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**re.findall** is a very useful function in python regular expressions world.

```
text="I'm new to python and trying to find a best way to search for some specific 
keywords 'coming soon', 'under construction', 'page not found' and 'forbidden'. I need 
to find all possible hits for those strings example: 'coming soon', 'Coming Soon', 
'coMInG SoOn' etc."

import re 
Hits=re.findall("(coming soon)", text, re.I)
print(Hits)
```

The output is as follows:

```
['coming soon', 'coming soon', 'Coming Soon', 'coMInG SoOn']
```

Python Documentation- https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html